# Wordpress - Frontend form Post title automatic generation using authors name

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced custom fields and custom post types ui, I need to generate a post name with the author's name in it, however this just prints "Solicitud", it seem like my variable $autor gets no value, is there any way I can fix this?

```
function my_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {

    $post2 = get_post($post_id);
    $autor=$post2->author;

    // Create a new post
    $post = array(
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_title'  => 'Solicitud' . $autor,
        'post_type'  => 'solicit',
    );

    // insert the post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

    // update $_POST['return']
    $_POST['return'] = add_query_arg( array('post_id' => $post_id), $_POST['return'] );

    // return the new ID
    return $post_id;
}

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_post' );
```

And, here is the code I use to create the form, I'm using acf_form:

```
$current_inv = $_GET['invid'];

/**
 * Template Name: Solicit
 */


acf_form_head(); 
get_header(); 

?>

    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">



            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php acf_form(array(
                    'post_id'   => 'new',
                    'field_groups'  => array( 243 ),
                    'submit_value'  => 'Crear el ticket'
                )); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'post_author' instead of 'author'. And also make sure that WP_Debug is set to TRUE while you're developing.

Here's a long version

```
function my_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // check if this is to be a new post
    if( $post_id != 'new' )
    {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Create a new post
    $post = array(
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_title'  => 'Solicitud',
        'post_type'  => 'solicit',
    );

    // insert the post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
    // Once we save, retrieve the original post so we can take the post_author
    $post2 = get_post($post_id);
    // Use post_author
    $autor = $post2->post_author;
    // Update the post with the new title
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, $post2->post_title . $autor));

    // update $_POST['return']
    $_POST['return'] = add_query_arg( array('post_id' => $post_id), $_POST['return'] );

    // return the new ID
    return $post_id;
}

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_post' );
```

Slightly shorter version which uses the current logged in user's username.

```
function my_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // check if this is to be a new post
    if( $post_id != 'new' )
    {
        return $post_id;
    }

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $author = $current_user->user_login; // OR [user_firstname, user_lastname, display_name]
    // Create a new post
    $post = array(
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_title'  => 'Solicitud' . $author,
        'post_type'  => 'solicit',
    );

    // insert the post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );    

    // update $_POST['return']
    $_POST['return'] = add_query_arg( array('post_id' => $post_id), $_POST['return'] );

    // return the new ID
    return $post_id;
}

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_post' );
```

References:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post
- http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/using-acf_form-to-create-a-new-post/
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user